# deploy nextjs with nginx with 403 forbidden

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nginx, next.js

I use nextjs as frontend and django as backend

in develpment stage everythings work

**but in production raise  /_next/static/chunks ... 403 Forbidden Error**

my nginx config doesnt work properly

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name <server_name> <www.server_name>;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;     
        root /{my_dir}/client/.next/;

        location /static {

                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;

                # For testing cache - remove before deploying to production
                # add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
        }
        location /_next/static {

                #proxy_cache STATIC;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;

                # For testing cache - remove before deploying to production
        # add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
        }
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }


}
```

I tried different nginx configs

- anyone can help me?

Comment: hey @Ehsan, do you find any solution for the "403 forbidden" error? I also have the same problem

Answer (score -1):

try config ssl for your websites (https)

here is a website that give you certificate for free : https://certbot.eff.org/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33612206)